# Geofence with multiple transitions Types set - Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Im confused with the Android Geofence Api. So the method says .setTransitionTypes(int). However when ever I try to set my geofence to monitor both enter and exit of a particular geofence, it only monitors the transition type of the Transition that I set it to monitor.

Here is an Example of my code

```
public Geofence toGeofence() {
// Build a new Geofence object
return new Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId(getId())
        .setTransitionTypes(getTransitionType()) //Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
        .setTransitionTypes(getTransitionType2())// Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT
        .setCircularRegion(
                getLatitude(), getLongitude(), getRadius())
        .setExpirationDuration(mExpirationDuration)
        .build();}
```

This only monitors the last transition type set which is the exit transition, I have resorted to creating 2 geofences for the same area, one to monitor each transition but I feel like that isnt the way to go. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who may come across this problem the way to set multiple transition types is by adding a    |   in between each transition type.

```
geofence.setTransitionType(getTransitionType() | getTransitionType2());
```

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin use this:

```
geofence.setTransitionType(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
```

Answer (score 2):

For adding multiple geofence transition type you can use `|` for java and for kotlin you have to use `or` keyword between transition types. For more ref [Create geofence objects](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#create-geofence-objects) from android developer doc

for Java

> new Geofence.Builder().setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

For Kotlin

> Geofence.Builder().setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)